# css with percent + static value

Tags: css

I know the following is wrong but what's the easier way to generate something similar?

```
 .classhere{
 width: 50px + 10%
 }
```

So the div here has a minimun of 50px width +10% (let's say the parent is 100px) so 55px and when the parent goes fullscreen e.g. 1800px the .classhere has a width of 50+180px.

**Update:**

javascript, jQuery and other solutions are welcome

Comment: This isn't possible without javascript http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/1024/centered-2-column-layout-with-fixed-width-and-percentage-wid/p1

Comment: ok, that's not a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like followed.

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
}

.child{
    background-color:green;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".child").width(50+($(".parent").width()*0.1));
    $(".child").height(50);
});
```

If you want to see a demo of it, the jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zbv27/)

Comment: Thanks, the child is not fluid though. I changed parent's width to a percent and the child stays with the same width

Comment: Then you have done something wrong, I also tested with fluid parent width and it worked like expected.

Comment: that's what I've tried: http://jsfiddle.net/zbv27/1/ The child is not responsive (maybe that's the key word I didn't say before)

Comment: ok, i see your problem, you need to bind the resize event. you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/zbv27/3/

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use javascript to get the width of the screen and then set the width. http://api.jquery.com/width/

Answer (score 1):

Though it's not supported on Android or in Opera, CSS calc() is made for this kind of stuff.

Reference this for browser compatibility: http://caniuse.com/calc

```
.classhere{
    width: -webkit-calc(50px + 10%);
    width: -moz-calc(50px + 10%);
    width: calc(50px + 10%);
}
```